# How do i create a wavy decoration in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to create something similar to this one. Been searching on the documentation but didn't get the answer. Is there a way to create one using flutter?

if it's possible, an article/documentation link

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a custom clipper for this design, or you can make use of this lib to ease your work https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom paints, use this tool to generate a custom paint in an easy way:
https://fluttershapemaker.com/
tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnKgtKxRLX4